# how to remove www part from request url and redirect into it

Tags: linux, .htaccess, apache2

I have host with multiple domain pointed. i need to remove 'www' part from requested URL and redirect to it.

```
Ex: 1. www.abc.com rediect to abc.com
    2. www.xyz.com redirect to xyz.com
```

i need to this dynamically.

I used below url re-write to do that but its not working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.%{REQUEST_URI}\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/%{REQUEST_URI}\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

any help really appreciate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Comment: The `REQUEST_URI` server variable is the requested _URL-path_, not the _second level domain_. (?!)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect www to non-www and it isapplies only for http URLs. You can change it to https if required. If you are writing this configuration in `.htaccess` file, you need to make you have the right `AllowOverride` config option. Otherwise, the `.htaccess` file will not be executed.